# Blockchain.info customer service

Tags: blockchain.info

Anyone know the the blockchain.com direct/ live customer service? I had submit several request with same problem , what i get is only the standard answer from blockchain.com which i feel is total nonsense.

Long story short , there is a transaction d69c2c14897a516917932f0ed0c2e04ed0380c63709d103d66541e6c77e34406 which shall be already confirmed, but blockchain.info shows unconfirmed transaction and the BTC cant be credit which the wallet also belong to blockchain.com. Therefore need help on the live/ real customer service.

Below are the standard template i get as reply.

> Friday at 12:28
>   Please check transaction d69c2c14897a516917932f0ed0c2e04ed0380c63709d103d66541e6c77e34406.
>   By using other platform ( at least 3 ) this transaction had been confirmed but not on blockchain.info. Unfortunately the 0.2 yet to debit in to 18hBv8j15E4iDJ7V7pKKiJN4hGvyRZCvkb wallet, it was suppose to as the transaction had been confirmed.
>
> confirmation 2.JPG (60 KB)
>    confirmation 1.JPG (70 KB)
>   Avatar
>   Tanya
>
> Saturday at 07:10
>   Hello,
>
> I'm sorry to hear about this trouble you're having. I can give you a little more information on how transaction confirmations work. An unconfirmed transaction will eventually either be accepted into a block by a mining pool and confirmed. Or it will be rejected by the network, if not rebroadcast, usually within 7 days. If it eventually is rejected, don't worry, the funds will remain on the address they were sent from. At this point, we can only recommend that you wait to see if your transaction is accepted into a block.
>
> Like all wallet providers, Blockchain has no control over the speed of confirmation, and unfortunately cannot expedite transactions. This is always dependent upon the network of miners.
>
> We do everything we can to lessen the number of pending transactions. For this reason, your Blockchain wallet utilizes dynamic bitcoin fees that are dependent upon current network conditions. To learn more about how this works read our blog here: https://blog.blockchain.com/2016/03/16/introducing-dynamic-fees/.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question was asked a few years ago, but for anyone else with a similar issue: If your wallet isn't working the way you want it to, just create another wallet using a different service. There's no reason you need to get them to fix anything unless you want them to. They aren't stopping you from transferring your funds because they have no control over your funds.

Always make sure you have your private keys or seed saved securely somewhere in case your wallet disappears or breaks in some way. That way, you can set up a new wallet to access the very same funds any time that becomes necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried reaching out to the Blockchain support on Twitter about this: https://twitter.com/murchandamus/status/1059594999476547585

I hope they'll get back to you.

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately, not replying at all. Any other idea? By the way, the link you post on twitter seems not linking .

Comment: They've replied about thirty minutes ago about having gotten the message and following up with you.

Comment: Thousand thanks Murch!! Let see will they reply your tweet. Till now I still get nothing.

Comment: Dear Murch ,could you please help me a favour. Blockchain is not replying me and the status is still the same. Could you help me to tweet them again, I tried but there is no reply from them. I would need help for publicity as I think this is sort of scam which blockchain is ignoring everything for their mistake . Really much appreciated and thousand thanks!

Comment: I've posted it here again: https://twitter.com/murchandamus/status/1060647801464414208